# ListBox item highlighted or selected confusion

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, listbox

in my ListBox , I have 5 numbers 1 - 5 , SelectedItem is databind in TwoWay Mode to SelectedAmount , an int property which has a default value of 1 , whenever I run  the Application I have 1 as value selected and highlighted on my ListBox, thats very good but now whenever I change the value to 2 or any other value , the ListBox shows the new value but it is not highlighted , and the SelectedAmount is still holding the old value , that is obviously bad , I want whenever the user changes the selected value, SelectedAmount to get the new value directly , the user now after he made his selection,had to click again to highlight it. any ideas ?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SiliconAmounts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SiliconAmount,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="4" />
```

my property databind to selectedItem looks like

```
public int SiliconAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return _SiliconAmount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SiliconAmount != value)
            {
                _SiliconAmount =value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SiliconAmount");
            }
        }
    }
```

my items property looks like

```
public ObservableCollection<int> SiliconAmounts
    {
        get { return _SiliconAmounts; }
        set
        {
            if (_SiliconAmounts != value)
            {
                _SiliconAmounts = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SiliconAmounts");
            }
        }
    }
```

on my viewModel constructor

```
SiliconAmounts = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        SiliconAmounts.Add(1);
        SiliconAmounts.Add(2);
        SiliconAmounts.Add(3);
        SiliconAmounts.Add(4);
        SiliconAmounts.Add(5);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you show code to reproduce this?

Comment: sure, I will edit the post to  include code

Comment: I have no idea if this works but try SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem.

Comment: I did,  the same problem

Comment: Check the Output pane in VS for any binding errors. Are all of the bindings set up properly? How are you establishing the data context of the ListBox? All of the code that you show here looks good.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the SiliconAmount set property, does the breakpoint get hit when the selection changes?

Comment: Ok to be perfectly clear, when you say change to another value it shows the value but not highlighted. Doesn't it show the value all along? And by changing do you mean by clicking on it in the ListBox or from code behind?

Comment: @Josh G , nothing wrong with the code , however because it is my first WPF application now I got where the problem is , it is the style that cause me problems, when running it with the default ControlTemplate , it is obvious for the user which value is currently selected , because it shows two values at the same time one is actually highlighted, but with the style it shows only one and the highlighted one is may be off the sight, I'm going to increase the size to see what will happen

Comment: that code works perfectly here (.Net 4.0). The only minor problem is that when I add SiliconAmount = 1 to set the initial value after initializing the collection, the current item is highlighted with a gray color instead of the default blue. For the rest, no problems. Are you sure your OnPropertyChanged implementation works properly?

Comment: @stijn yeah, see my reply to Josh G , the problem is more UX than code/syntax now, after increasing the size of the ListBox, user will know which value he is actually selecting, because when he press the up or down arrows, he would be able to see the highlighted value, I hope I did explain well my thoughts here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting and reading the comments, it sounds like the problem is UI styling. I have found that Expression Blend is a helpful tool for writing styles and templates on controls. I tend to like to code direct XAML quite a bit, but Expression has an editor for this and some nice tools for setting up visual states, visual triggers, selecting colors, and more. [You can get a trial of Blend here](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx). Another tool a lot of WPF developers use is [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/).

Comment: Read the comments on the OP. After questions and answers he discovered (as we suspected) that there wasn't any problem with his code, the problem was with the styling of the ListBox and other controls. So I gave him some suggestions on creating styles.